# how to make high latency in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, streaming, latency

I want to live stream with ffmpeg to YouTube, but I want to wait for it to make high latency, which is to wait for the encode for 2-3 minutes and then stream it to YouTube. How to ? I can't get an answer on the internet, because most are looking for low latency, while I need normal latency - high latency

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more direct way, but you can always use two separate FFmpeg processes and a file on disk as a buffer.

Matroska files are useful for this.  They can be written to and read from simultaneously.  (As long as the read side doesn't catch up to the write side, of course.)

So, process one is like:

```
ffmpeg -i some_input -vcodec libx264 -b:v 9M -acodec aac -b:a 192k buffer.mkv
```

Then, wait a couple minutes and start a process to stream to YouTube that reads from the first process in realtime:

```
ffmpeg -re -i buffer.mkv -codec copy rtmps://something.youtube.com/example
```

One potential caveat is that a realtime input doesn't necessarily match realtime from whatever the live input device is.  It's probably close enough for most purposes, but if you're going to run this for days, keep in mind that clocks may drift.

Also, you'll need to have enough storage for the entire length of the stream.
If you don't have the disk space for the whole thing, you might try a segmented format like HLS, in place of the Matroska example.